# Windows Server 2016 Hyper-v host 3 websites in 3 VM with One Public IP

Tags: windows, routing, windows-server-2016, ip-routing

Installed is Windows Server 2016 DCE as host OS. I want to host three websites on three different guest VMs under this host. I got one public IP (5.189.175.xxx), which is assigned to the host.

**No Website** or IIS is currently running on the host.

I have created three guests (Server 2016) with external virtual switch (192.168.225.5/24). Each website is hosted in IIS by itself and is working properly (in the local host network ONLY).

- VM 1 [Windows server 2016] *Website 1* [www.example1.com] (192.168.225.10 )
- VM 2 [[Windows server 2016] *Website 2* [www.example2.com] (192.168.225.11 )
- VM 3 [Windows server 2016] *Website 3* [www.example3.com] (192.168.225.12 )

In ISPs DNS I have pointed all the 3 site to:

- example.com `A Record` 5.189.175.xxx [ Public Static IP ]
- www.example.com `A Record` 5.189.175.xxx
- example1.com `A Record` 5.189.175.xxx [ Public Static IP ]
- ... and so on.

Now all the websites (URLs) are pointing to the host, but I want to redirect each website to its own VM.

Comment: You will need to configure a reverse proxy.

Comment: Please describe in detail ?

Comment: Google results for `iis reverse proxy`: [1st](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/), [2nd](https://tecadmin.net/set-up-reverse-proxy-using-iis) & [3rd](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis). Pick any.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a reverse proxy on your host, which redirects all the requests to the correct guest VMs. I personlly would recommend IIS with ARR (Application Request Routing), but almost every webserver is capabale of actin as such.